# Why is the label after the input box?

Tags: css

I just can't seem to figure this out even after fiddling with the float variable.
The "Q1" appears after the label :/

```
<div class="question active">Q1<input id="one" type="text"></div>


.question {
    display: none;
    float:left
}
.question.active,.question.answered {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;

}
.question.active input {
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
.question.answered input {
    border: 0px solid black;
    float: left;
}
.button {
    display: none;
}
.button.active {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.clickbutton {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}

.focusField{
    border:solid 2px #73A6FF;
    background:#EFF5FF;
    color:#000;
}
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I was actually expecting a `<label>` element in your markup.

Comment: and what exactly is the label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `input` is `floated` left.

```
.question.active input {
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

This places it before the text in your `.question.active div`.

If you placed the **Q1** in a `label` and floated that left first, it would all work out.

Comment: Or better yet, don't float the input element at all. Only float the div it lives in; all of the div's content will be floated with it.